# Angular: Selecting elements from DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using an ng-repeat to create items. I would like to determine the height of each element that is created by using a function.

I know how to pass the index of the element that is created by ng-repeat to the function that should determine the height, but I'm getting stuck in actually selecting that item.

This is what I'm using now:

```
   $scope.getItemHeight = function(index) { // index is index of element in ng-repeat
    var itemHeight = angular.element('li').eq('+index+').offsetHeight;
    return itemHeight;
   };
```

But that doesn't work due to error: `Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!`

I also tried:

```
   $scope.getItemHeight = function(index) {
    var itemHeight = document.querySelectorAll('ul:nth-child('+index+')');
    return itemHeight;
   };
```

This returns an element with length 0 so the selector doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/squrler/pen/LxsfE?editors=101

---

**EDIT:**
What I want is not possible at this time. More information here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1691

Comment: Don't you want to get the `li`? I think you'd want `document.querySelectorAll('ul > li:nth-child('+index+')');`

Comment: Ah, sorry typo, you're right, I am looking for the li. But unfortunately that still returns an element of length 0. :(

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing any DOM calculations/manipulation in a directive? This should really be abstracted away from the controller.

Comment: Some more background: this example uses a directive from the Ionic framework called collection-repeat. (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/) It defines a specific function to specify the height of an element. I just need a way to actually determine that height. When that works I can proceed to put it in a directive, but for now any help in actually finding the element and determining it's height would be really helpful.

Comment: At first blush, I'm not entirely sure about the quality of the solution that `collection-repeat` directive is offering. It seems like you're after some sort of "infinite scroll" repeater? Generally speaking, if you need an "infinite scroll", your usability *might* be failing. [Here's a good article on some of the pros and cons](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/03/infinite-scrolling-lets-get-to-the-bottom-of-this/)

Comment: Collection-repeat is specifically meant for mobile devices that very easily choke on even very small ng-repeat generated lists. More than 50-70 elements can already make scrolling on lower end Android devices extremely slow. That's the background for the collection-repeat directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:  After looking at this further it seems a bit more complicated.  The directive that is firing the repeater needs to run in order for the lis to be rendered, as the li is rendered (assuming you move this to a directive) it triggers the directive to get its height, but the li and it's corresponding data are not yet fully rendered and thus have no height.  If you wait for the rendering using timeout, the repeater will just continue rendering without valid height data while the timeout waits. So it seems you have a bit of a conundrum.  You might try using http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/ or something of the like.

This should be put in a directive which will give you easy access to the li as it is rendered.

Something like:

```
.directive('getHeight', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var li = element[0];
            var height = li.offsetHeight;
            console.log('Height': height)
        }
    };
}]);
```

Not sure what you're looking to do with the height once you have it...

Otherwise you can just go:

```
var ul=document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var li=ul.getElementsByTagName('li')[index];
var height=li.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this. For why I need that height, check out my response to Marks comment on my question.

Comment: Updated the Codepen: your second suggestion doesn't select the li element for some reason.

Comment: That's because, since it's a repeater the li is not yet rendered.  It doesn't exist until the data it's bound to exists.  You'll see if you put a setTimout of a second or so the li will be selected.

Comment: No luck with the timeout, even with 3 seconds.. :( Updated the Codepen again. Now trying with the directive.

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't lead to the desired result I'm afraid. Right now the function returns '53', where it actually needs to return the height of the calculated li. But you're right, since the li by this stage isn't rendered yet, this won't work. I think your directive is needed for that.

Comment: Yes it seems it's a bit more complicated I updated the post with further information.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to look at this @AdamMatthews. After discussing this with the developer of the directive we can conclude that what I'm after is not currently possible. More background here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1691